# Determing why an H.264 file doesn't work on iOS

Tags: ios, h.264, video-encoding

Given a H.264 file, is there a reliable way to determine whether it will work on a particular iOS device by analyzing the file itself, and if incompatible, determine why?

I am working on a project now, where I have been given a lot of .mp4 files.  All of them work in a normal desktop environment (eg, Chrome will play them in a `<video>` element).  A large number of them don't work in iOS.

I have run them through [ffprobe](http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffprobe.html) and compared the results to the [technical specs](http://support.apple.com/kb/SP647) for the device I am testing with.  Nothing seems out of whack.  For example, one of the bad files looks like it is Main profile, 640x480, level 3.1, 29.97fps, 1Mbps in the proper container format.  In other words, pretty vanilla H.264.

I know I could re-encode everything, but I don't just want to solve the problem, I want to understand why it was a problem in the first place in order to prevent it the next time.